# CakePHP send emails daily

Tags: cakephp, heroku, cron, email

I am new to CakePHP and I am making an application where users fill out forms and then other users who are specified on the form have to add to the data. At the end of each day I want to send an email to all users who have been referenced on forms that day and tell them how many new forms they need to add information to.

I know how to run my query to figure out who I need to email and how to construct the email, but how do I make it happen once a day or at any set time? I have found something about cron jobs in my research but I don't fully understand or know if that will work for me. I am working in a Windows environment and launching my app on a heroku server currently.

Thanks for any info!

Cheers, 
  Jon

Answer (score 2):

Although this question is not really related to CakePHP but rather to Heroku, I suggest you install that [Heroku Scheduler Addon](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler).

Once installed, you can write a shell script, such as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh

php -f path_to/your_php_file/which_sends_emails.php
```

and name it sendemailjob.sh or something. Make it executable by

```
sudo chmod +x sendemailjob.sh
```

After that, you just need to tell Heroku Scheduler to daily execute that file. Should not be too much magic.

Although I am not quite sure whether you actually have shell access since you're on Windows, maybe there is a different solution for Windows.